# Are parse objects saved to the cloud transformed to corresponding JavaScript Class object?

Tags: parse-platform

Sorry that this is a pretty general question. I am developing an android app using Parse, and when I call:

```
ParseObject obj;
//add some key-value pairs
obj.saveInBackground();
```

How is this object exactly represented on the server/cloud, is it transformed to the corresponding JavaScript object(class)?

And if I retrieve this object with cloud code, can I regard it as the corresponding JavaScript Class object. e.g. ParseGeoPoint ==> Parse.GeoPoint, and I can use that object retrieved on cloud in the `withinKilometers` JavaScript Parse.Query Method?

Comment: Yes, sounds right(ish)

Comment: Can you elaborate why it is an 'ish'? ^_^

Comment: The server stores data in JSON IIRC. Cloud code happens to be in JavaScript so you get objects in that language

Comment: I see, so If I retrieve a ParseObject, and then put a new key-value pair to it, and then call .saveInBackground(); will it be saved as a new object or just updating the same one?

Comment: update the one you pulled down (or the existing one with the specified object id)

Comment: I see, thank you very much :-)